# Force the user to enter data in first cell of the DataGridRow

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid. In this datagrid new rows are added programatically.

When a new row is added, the first cell of new row is focused.

Now, if user clicks on any other cell without entering data in the first cell, then focus should not move from first cell. I mean I want the user to enter data in first cell. If he don't want to enter data in first cell, then he/she should press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If he wants to edit any other cell from any other row, then he should be able to do it. But when he again comes to the new row, then he should be forced to focus the first cell

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want focus to move to any other column in the new row, you can disable all the elements of that row.

Now whenever user press an Enter or he/she input some text to the first column of the new row, enable all the elements of that row.

For example, consider the two TextBox. Initially second textbox will be disabled. When user press enter or any data in first TextBox, second TextBox will get enabled.

XAML code:

```
<TextBox Name="txtBox" Grid.Row="0" KeyDown="txtBox_KeyDown" TextChanged="txtBox_TextChanged"></TextBox>
<TextBox Name="txtBox2" Grid.Row="1" IsEnabled="False"></TextBox>
```

C# Code:

```
private void txtBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            txtBox2.IsEnabled = true;
            txtBox2.Focus();
        }
    }

    private void txtBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!txtBox.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            txtBox2.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            txtBox2.IsEnabled = false;
        }
    }
```

You can use the same concept to solve your issue.

Comment: It is very easy for 2 textbox controls. I have tried to disable other cells of the same row if first cell is empty. But now the problem is when first cell is empty and if the user click or press tab on any other cell(which disabled), I can see the CellEditingTemplate. Though it is disabled, the textbox inside CellEditingTemplate will not get focused but the cell itself gets the focused. I would like first cell to be focused (if it is empty) even if user clicks on any disabled cell. And Thanks for sharing your ideas and great effort.